# What were the other colors and powers of Maerlyn's Rainbow?

Tags: stephen-king, the-dark-tower

We are told that Maerlyn's Rainbow is made up of 13 crystal balls. Roland encounters two:

- Pink: the power of sight - both present and of the future
- Black: the power to travel between realities

That leaves 11 other crystal balls unaccounted for. What were the colors and abilities of the remaining crystal balls?

Comment: We have very little info about other balls, all colors, locations of only few of them, nothing about powers, I think. They were fragile, so some of them probably didn't survive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maerlyn%27s_Rainbow):

> According to The Dark Tower: The Gunslinger Born #2 (March 7, 2007) the thirteen bends are: Crimson, Orange, Yellow, Pink, Dark Blue, Dark Green, Indigo, Lime, Azure, Violet, Brown, Pearl Grey, and Black.

Presumably, since it cites its source it can be considered reliable, but I haven't read it and so can't confirm this.